# GeoServer homepage is showing GeoWebCache homepage

Tags: geoserver

For some reason, when I go to
`localhost:8080/geoserver` , instead of redirecting to `localhost:8080/geoserver/web`, it shows following screen
[image]

what might be the reson?

Comment: how did you install GeoServer? what have you changed recently?

Comment: I have installed via binary and added a geofence server plugin ..that's all :/

Comment: then you broke something with the GeoFence install

Comment: I simply copied the jar form geofence server zip to lib folder.

Comment: If I remove geofence plugin jars, it is working fine. But then how can I use geofence correctly? I read that I should not add both client and server .jars  I should only add the server, right?

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved. Add the following property:

```
gwc.context.suffix=gwc
```

into the `geofence-server.properties` file

Reference Link: https://github.com/geoserver/geofence/issues/102

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.20.6 add `-Dgwc.context.suffix=gwc` to the GeoServer JAVA_OPTS